# Defining a C++ conversion operator that doesn't return a value

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following example, note `A::operator B()` does not return a value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct B
{
    int valb;
    B(int x = 10) : valb(x) {
        printf("\nB::B()...\n");
    }
    B(const B& rhs) : valb(rhs.valb) {
        printf("\nB::B(const B&)...\n");
    }
    B(B& rhs) : valb(rhs.valb) {
       printf("\nB::B(B&)...\n");
    }
    void f() const {
        printf("\nB::f() const... [%d | 0x%x]\n", valb, this);
    }
    ~B() {
        printf("\nB::~B()...\n");
    }
};

struct A {
    static int gv;
    int *vala;
    A(int *x = &gv) : vala(x) {
        printf("\nA::A()...\n");
    }
    A(const A& rhs) : vala(rhs.vala) {
        printf("\nA::A(const A&)...\n");
    }
    void f() const {
        printf("\nconst A::f()...\n");
    }
    operator B () {
        printf("\nA::operator B()... [0x%x]\n", this);
        // return B();
    }
};

void func(const B& barg) {
    printf("\nfunc(const B&)...\n");
    barg.f();
}

int A::gv;

int main ()
{
    A a1;

    func(a1);

    return 0;
}
```

When built in rhel5 with g++ 4.5.2 (-std=gnu++0x -fno-elide-constructors), the following output is generated:

> `A::A()...`
>
> `A::operator B()... [0x1cc30200]`
>
> `func(const B&)...`
>
> `B::f() const... [4196240 | 0x1cc30210]`
>
> `B::~B()...`

Note the 2 different addresses displayed indicate 2 different objects are being created.

Questions:

1. Why isn't any `B` constructor invoked?
2. Within `func()`, how is the B object over which `B::f()` is called, created?
3. Shouldn't g++ have generated a compilation error?
4. Is there any hint in the standard's Section 12.3.2 that would make the above output valid/expected?

Comment: You mean a warning like this g++4.8.1? *warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]* Did you use `-Wall`?

Comment: You have *undefined behaviour*. Not much point getting too analytical about UB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing is that it is undefined behavior, as the conversion operator is not returning anything.

> Why isn't any B constructor invoked?

Because there is no B object created in the program.

> Within func(), how is the B object over which B::f() is called, created?

It is not created. The program has undefined behavior, it is assuming that the reference refers to a `B` object, but there is no `B` object at that memory location (due to the failure to create it in `operator B`.

> Shouldn't g++ have generated a compilation error?

With high enough warning and maybe some optimization level you would have got a warning. The standard does not require a diagnostic, so this is just quality of implementation.

> Is there any hint in the standard's Section 12.3.2 that would make the above output valid/expected?

There is nothing that can make that *expected*, but it is clearly valid by the standard, since your program causes undefined behavior, whatever the compiler does and whatever you see happening is one valid incarnation of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Falling off the end of a non-`void` function (other than `main()`) without a `return`-statement is undefined behavior. Whatever happens is what you get. If you are lucky, you get a crash.

The reason it isn't an error is that the flow of control may never really end up falling off the end of a function but the compiler can't necessarily see that, e.g.

```
#include <stdexcept>

int f(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("index out of range");
    }
    return 17;
}

int g() {
    f(0);
    // compile-time error would be invalid
}

int main() {
    try { g(); }
    catch (std::exception const&) { }
}
```

In the above code the compiler *could* detect that `f()` never returns when called with `0` but if `f()` is coming from some library, it is generally impossible to predict.

Comment: This is what C++11 **`[[noreturn]]`** is all about. Since Visual C++ doesn't support that, and probably never will (about that much was stated once), I use a macro `CPPX_NORETURN` that is defined differently for different compilers. For Visual C++ a `__declspec`, IIRC.

Comment: Oh, there is an additional Visual C++ issue. The main use of `CPPX_NORETURN` is for a function `bool fail( string const& message );`, that throws a `std::system_error` (or derived), but then VC++ complains about a non-`void` function not returning a value. And if a `return` statement is added it complains about that. Sort of can't be satisfied. So I also turn off that specific silly-warning.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: My function `f()` _will_ return a value when called with a different parameter than `0`! The contract is, however, that it will throw an exception when it is called with `0` (admittedly, I didn't write out the contract o the function). That is even `[[noreturn]]` or any other amount of static annotation will help the compiler to detect that `f()` doesn't return! Maybe for `f()` it could figure it out but I'm pretty sure that the problem is equivalent to the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) in general.

Comment: I would solve that simply by introducing an inline `[[noreturn]]` wrapper for the no-return case of `f`. :-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: The general case is not tractable with whatever amount of refactoring or annotation. Yes, trivial cases can be made such that the compiler can find what's going on and compiler are generally pretty smart tracking these things. Requiring an error if a function could fall off the end would still be wrong because it would need to cope with the general case and I'd rather have compiler now than someone implementing a compiler capable of deciding the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) (which is, AFAIK, never).

Comment: Oh, a standard `[[mayreturn]]` attribute would go a long way towards permitting suitable *practical* diagnostics for both the intentional and inadvertent case. All that's needed is someone to write the proposal, and someone to champion it. I think. ;-) Of course the ideal would be to require every path to return a value unless `[[noreturn]]` or `[[mayreturn]]` is specified. But that could conceivably break a lot of code, so.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: why bother, though? Turn on warnings and most compiler will emit a suitable message. I'd rather submit proposals dealing making it better to deal with correct problems.

Comment: Uh, rather, turn **off** the relevant warnings (as I mentioned for Visual C++), on a compiler-specific basis, and there you have it. But of course, a novice will first have to turn on warnings in general.

Comment: a missing "return" isnt an obvious error? Regardless of whether f() returns or throws, missing the "return f(0)" will always fail and should be treated as an error, not a warning. No?

Comment: @excalibur: why would it be an error? The code sample is perfectly valid! ... and in other cases with a forced return value a static analyzer _may_ complain about the artificial `return`-statement being unreachable. The C++ standard definitely restricts the undefined behavior to actually flowing off the end of a function (6.6.3 [stmt.return] paragraph 2, last sentence): "... Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behaviorin a value-returning function."

Answer (score 3):

You have **Undefined Behavior** in the conversion operator. Anything can happen, or not. Among the things that didn't happen in this particular case, was construction of a B.

Here is an equivalent program (for ordinary invocation with less than 55 arguments):

```
int main( int, char* argv[] ) { return *argv[55]; }
```